# Как выделить предыдущую строку в DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Есть грид. При нажатии на строку в гриде, отображается в текстбоксах доп. информация. Доп.информацию пользователь может изменять. ВСе изменения проверяются на корректность. Если данные введены некорректно или вообще не введены, необходимо запретить переход на другую строку в гриде. Можно ли как-то отменить выделение новой строки или, на крайний случай, выделить предыдущую строку?

Comment: Как насчет [такого](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ykdxa0bc(v=vs.110).aspx) способа?

Comment: пример очень хороший. Но это когда редактирование непосредственно в гриде. И выходит так, что, из режима редактирования в ячейке, не выйти. У меня редактирование в textbox. После вывода сообщения о некорректных данных на другую строку переход не осуществялется, но при попытке внести значение мне оаять выбивает сообщение об ошибке...

Comment: Тогда можно навесить [валидацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.110).aspx) на текстбоксы. А вообще, лучше позволить юзеру вводить данные в удобной ему последовательности. При этом просто помечая значком ошибки строки грида с неверными данными. А уже при переходе к следующему шагу: сохранении данных в БД/файл, закрытии формы редактирования и т. п. - не пускать его, пока не исправит данные.

Answer (score 2):

При выборе строки стоит записывать в переменную-накопитель RowIndex , далее при неправильном вводе :

```
dataGridView1.Rows[nRowIndex].Selected = true;//nRowIndex - переменная накопитель
dataGridView1.Rows[nRowIndex].Cells[0].Selected = true;
```

Можно сделать nRowIndex-1; Дабы перейти на строку перед этой

Comment: К какому событию подписаться, чтобы написать этот код?

Comment: Я бы привязался к - CellValueChanged , или к SelectionChanged